# Adding more images to pure CSS slider

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand how the math behind this pure CSS slider works? [https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/kFoGw?limit=all&page=1&q=image+slider](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/kFoGw?limit=all&page=1&q=image%20slider)

My goal is to turn it into a seven image slider.

For example, every time I add another image to the rotation it messes the slider up (two images stack on top of each other.) I would like to understand the calculation so each will display at the full width of the slider for 30s.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Istok+Web);
@keyframes slidy {
    0% { left: 0%; }
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
     }
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, figure { 
   margin: 0; background: #101010;
   font-family: Istok Web, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 100;
}
div#captioned-gallery { 
   width: 100%; overflow: hidden; 
}
figure.slider { 
  position: relative; width: 500%;
  font-size: 0; animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
figure.slider figure { 
  width: 20%; height: auto;
  display: inline-block;  position: inherit; 
 }
figure.slider img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
figure.slider figure figcaption { 
 position: absolute; bottom: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 color: #fff; width: 100%;
 font-size: 2rem; padding: .6rem; 
}
```

```html
<base href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/">
<div id="captioned-gallery">
<figure class="slider">
    <figure>
        <img src="hobbiton-lake.jpg" alt>
        <figcaption>Hobbiton, New Zealand</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="wanaka-drowned-tree.jpg" alt>
        <figcaption>Wanaka, New Zealand</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="utah-peak.jpg" alt>
        <figcaption>Utah, United States</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="bryce-canyon-utah.jpg" alt>
        <figcaption>Bryce Canyon, Utah, United States</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="hobbiton-lake.jpg" alt>
        <figcaption>Hobbiton, New Zealand</figcaption>
    </figure>
    </figure>
    </div>
```

Comment: basically each slide you need to move `left` by `-100%`,  the percentage where the `left` stays the same is the amount of time the slider spends on that slide before moving on.  So if you wanted to add another slide, you need to go to `left:-500%` and redistribute the percentages down the left and you may also want to increase the animation time from 30s to 35s for the extra slide

Comment: Here is an updated slider for 7 images with a few comments to what i have changed: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qxbjge?limit=all&page=1&q=image%20slider

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add more images to your slider, add more `<figures></figures>` tags to your slider class. For example:

```
<figure>
    <img src="YOUR_IMAGE_HERE.jpg" alt>
    <figcaption>NEW IMAGE, FOUND IN YOUR FOLDER</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Just remember to keep this within the `<figure class="slider"> </figure>`. In your CSS you will also find code for how many seconds the animation should use. That's how you can extend/decrease the limit of each slide.

Comment: Spec, thanks for the feedback. When I add another figure (image +caption) to the html, the slider breaks. I'm assuming it's because the CSS is written for 5 images. I'm wondering what calcuation is used in the CSS to make 5 images slide fullscreen (one at a time) at 30s a piece?

Comment: Yes, the CSS is written for 5 images exactly. To change that you need to edit the keyframes. I can see that Paul who commented underneath me has already gone through the last question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the original has only four (different!) images, you need five figures (first and last are the same) to achieve the effect of never-ending sliding.

Then, you need to set `figure.slider`'s width to 700% (7 instead of 5 figures) and add four additional keyframes to the slidy animation. Right now, each of the four images stays visible for 20% of the animation, while the transition takes up 5% each (times four = 20%); this gives the total of 100% of animation length.
You would need to divide that into nice segments for six different images, e.g. 0, 13, 17, 30, 34, 47, 51, 64, 68, 81, 85, 97, 100 (note: it's not totally even but close enough). Lastly, adjust the percentage offset.

Now, add two additional figure elements into the slider (best somewhere in the middle) and there you go.

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pagwJP?limit=all&page=1&q=image%20slider)** (I moved the caption to the top and put numbers in. Now you can clearly see the slider with six different images.)

Comment: Thanks Paul, this is super helpful. So, I need to set figure.slider's width to 800% (8 figures for 7 different images), then divide 100/7 to get the keyframe segments. Each segment should be 14.285, which leaves 11% seconds on screen and a 3% transition? https://codepen.io/shannon-hart82/pen/BYjZzjSomething is off with my keyframes. –

Comment: You need to set each figure's width according to the actual number of elements (which is eight), thus `figure.slider figure { width: 12.5%; }`. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my analysis. There are 5 images of the same width to be shown over 30s. Divide 100% of the animation time by 5 images: 100%/5 = 20%. Also you will notice there are 5% jumps. I'm not sure but I think this is just to get a smoother animation (i.e. to get from 20% to 25%, the image "settles down"). So it's enough to say that if you need 6 images, then there should be 100%/6 = 16.67% jumps between each image.

```
@keyframes slidy {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  20% { left: 0%; }      // +20%
  25% { left: -100%; }
  45% { left: -100%; }   // +20%
  50% { left: -200%; }
  70% { left: -200%; }   // +20%
  75% { left: -300%; }
  95% { left: -300%; }   // +20%
  100% { left: -400%; }
}
```